# get count of has_many association in rails query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

I have a two `model`. `Post` and `Comment'.

`Post` has_may `comments`.

**Query:**
  I want to get the max count of comments in which post.

This should be done by `rail` query.

Comment: Can you please add comment who `down` vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@post = Post.
  joins(:comments).
  select('posts.*, count(comments.id) as comment_count').
  group("posts.id").
  first
```

Comment: I am looking for a query from which I can get the post which have max number of comments among other posts. Now do you understand?